# return distance with _source using Elasticsearch inside function_score

Tags: elasticsearch

Can anyone please tell me In ElasticSearch how to return distance using function_score my code is given below.

```
function_score: {
          query: {
            query_string: {
              query: shop_search,
              fields: [ 'shop_name', 'address.state', 'address.city', 'address.country', 'address.street'] 
            }
          },
//          boost: 5.0,
            gauss: {
              _score,
              location: { 
                origin: { lat:  12.8748964,
                  lon: 77.6413239
                },
                scale: "0.1km",
                offset: "0km",
                decay: "0.000005"
              }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are looking for the distance between  lat and lon you provide against each location field of each document right ?

Comment: yep now how can i get the value of distance returned inside the hits ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use script fields to achieve this.
Something like below should work for you -

```
{
    "query" : {
        ...
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "distance" : {
            "script" : "doc['location'].distanceInKm(12.8748964, 77.6413239)"
        }
    }
}
```

Please go through [this](https://qbox.io/blog/computing-distance-from-a-reference-point-with-script-fields-and-the-explain-api) and [this](http://blog.qbox.io/logging-and-scripted_fields-in-elasticsearch)  to get a better idea.

Comment: for using script_fields do i have to add something anywhere  or not??

Comment: Nothing , make sure the location field is of type geo_point , rest is straight forward.

Comment: search and lang groovy is disabled it is also showing that error ??

Comment: You have to enable dynamic scripting - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Comment: can you please tell me the what code should i write inside my /scripts folder for my above query variable distance also isn't there any other simple way possible ??

Comment: In simpler terms just tell me one thing https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html to use them what should i add in my yml file or should i have to add a other script file for using this please tell me i am very confused right now ??

Comment: In your elasticsearch.yml file , add this- " script.disable_dynamic: false"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89598/discussion-between-divanshu-pratap-and-vineeth-mohan).

Comment: first question i want solppy arc distance rather then plane distance second question as i am searching for distance above in my gauss function wouldn't you think it will be appropriate to return the distance from there instead of just calculating it again inside script_fields ??

Comment: If you want the gauss value computed , enabled explain flag and get this values from the explanation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-explain.html

Comment: also can you please tell me where i have to add the line script.disable_dynamic: false in my yml file please ??

Comment: i want the gauss functions distance of any point from the origin not the value ??

Comment: thanks it finally worked vineeth but 1 question instead of calculaing distance outside cant i just calculate it inside gauss function or it is not possible ??

Comment: In that case , use replace in boost_mode to negate out the score in query and use only the decay function. What you are looking would be there as _score per document.